# Error Uploading Audio Files With PHP

Tags: php, audio

I built a file upload form in PHP, IT WORKS fine when it comes to images, but it will not upload an audio file.

I can upload all (most) other files, but can't upload mp4/mp3/wav

It registers as no file for some reason (it won't even echo out the file information like it does with images and other files) My code works just well for other types of files.

I have searched for a solution before posting this.

The code is below and you may try it.

Here is the code:

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
    $UploadName = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['name'];
    $UploadTmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
    $UploadType = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
    $FileSize = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['size'];

    $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#","",$UploadName);

    echo $UploadName."</br>"; 
    echo $UploadTmp."</br>";
    echo $UploadType."</br>";
    echo $FileSize."</br>";

    if ($FileSize > 100000){
        die("Error - File Too Big");
    }

    if(!$UploadTmp){
        die("No File Selected, Please Upload Again");
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp,"Uploads/$UploadName");
    }
}
?>

<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.fileuploadholder{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 60px auto 0px auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fileuploadholder">
<label for="UploadFileField"></label>
<form action="FileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
<input type="file" name="UploadFileField" id="UploadFileField"/>
<input type="submit" name="UploadButton" value="Upload"/>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let's see if it is browser-related : did you try with miscellanous browsers (IE then opera then chrome etc...) and always failed ?

Comment: Did you check to see if there was an upload error? http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: The only member of the `$_FILES` array you never bother to check is the one you should check first `$_FILES['UploadFileField']['error']`

Comment: Have you checked your `php.ini` file to see what the `upload_max_filesize` and `max_input_time` and `max_execution_time` and `post_max_size` parameters are set to. Ausio files tend to be quite large, I would bet you have exceeded one of those maximums

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have checked the php.ini file and changed the upload_max_filesize to 80 MBs and I still have the problem. What do I set the other parameters to? I don't want to mess up my php.ini file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How big are the audio files you are uploading

Comment: And all these parameters are described in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly The files I' trying to upload are between around 4 MBs to 200MBs. Some are mp3, mp4, and wav. I made post_max_size equal to 800M, upload_max_filesize=500M, max_input_time=60, max_execution_time=30.

Comment: @bassxzero it returned a '1' saying my file was too big. I had to change upload_max_filesize and restart apache, Now it works!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I restart apache and the changes started working. Thanks!